# Eclipse refactor: change constructor method signature for all subclasses

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

In eclipse, is there a way refactor a superclass constructor method signature so that all of the subclass constructors with the same signature are also refactored in the same way?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

double left click on signature, then right click --> Refactor --> Change method signature.

Comment: This only changes the superclass constructor signature and does not change subclass constructor signatures.